# how to extract text between two delimiters when string is present

Tags: bash, text-parsing

I have a large data file which looks like:

```
//
ID   1.1.1.258
DE   6-hydroxyhexanoate dehydrogenase.
CA   6-hydroxyhexanoate + NAD(+) = 6-oxohexanoate + NADH.
CC   -!- Involved in the cyclohexanol degradation pathway in Acinetobacter
CC       NCIB 9871.
//
ID   1.1.1.259
DE   3-hydroxypimeloyl-CoA dehydrogenase.
CA   3-hydroxypimeloyl-CoA + NAD(+) = 3-oxopimeloyl-CoA + NADH.
CC   -!- Involved in the anaerobic pathway of benzoate degradation in
CC       bacteria.
//
ID   1.1.1.260
DE   Sulcatone reductase.
CA   Sulcatol + NAD(+) = sulcatone + NADH.
CC   -!- Studies on the effects of growth-stage and nutrient supply on the
CC       stereochemistry of sulcatone reduction in Clostridia pasteurianum,
CC       C.tyrobutyricum and Lactobacillus brevis suggest that there may be at
CC       least two sulcatone reductases with different stereospecificities.
//
```

I want to extract sections of this file that contain the work `anaerobic` . I specifically want the ID line.

Is there a means to search the file between ID and // to find `anaerobic`and print the output to a new file? If the whole section is printed that is fine as I figure I can grep it out after.

Expected out should be either

```
ID   1.1.1.259
```

or

```
ID   1.1.1.259
DE   3-hydroxypimeloyl-CoA dehydrogenase.
CA   3-hydroxypimeloyl-CoA + NAD(+) = 3-oxopimeloyl-CoA + NADH.
CC   -!- Involved in the anaerobic pathway of benzoate degradation in
CC       bacteria.
//
```

Comment: Please show expected output and work done so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's simple with awk

```
awk '/anaerobic/' RS='//\n' ORS='\n//' ./file.txt
```

Comment: This is great thanks. I can just grep the ID lines from here.

Comment: note that multi-character RS is GNU awk specific.. to get id only, `awk -F'\n' -v RS='//' '/anaerobic/{print $1}'`

Answer (score 2):

`tac file | sed -n '/anaerobic/,$p' | sed -n '/^ID/ {p;q}'`

- `tac **file**`: print file from end to beginning
- `sed -n '/anaerobic/,$p'`: print from first occurrence of anaerobic to the end of file
- `sed -n '/^ID/ {p;q}'`: search for a line starting with ID,
  print the first ocurrence only

Comment: This will print only one occurrence. There can be multiple sections that contain `anaerobic`.

Answer (score 2):

For variety, possible [`GNU sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) solution:

```
sed -nr ':a; \@(^|\n)//$@! { N; ba }; /anaerobic/p' data
```

---

- `-n` => suppresses automatic printing of pattern space
- `-r` => extended regular expressions
- `:a` => definition of a label
- `ba` => jumps to the label `a`
- `N` => appends next line to the pattern space
- `\@(^|\n)//$@!` => matches "sections" that don't end with `//`

`\@(^|\n)//$@! { N; ba }` therefore appends next line to the pattern spaces until it finds the `//` section delimiter. `/anaerobic/p` then checks if the current section contains `anaerobic` and if it does, `p`command prints it.